# What does the phrase "They would clash with my drapes" mean?

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms, phrase-meaning

I have come across this phrase in the sitcom, Hot in Cleveland wherein a gay man is asked if he had kids to which he responds with this phrase :"They would clash with my drapes." I tried looking it up on the internet but I have had no luck finding the meaning.

I would be glad if someone could kindly tell me as to what it means.

Here's a link to the episode and you could hear the phrase at 6:30

[Video](http://www.tvland.com/episodes/80183/hot-in-cleveland-cleveland-indians)

Comment: It's simply a joke. "Clash with my <some item of clothing or fashion>" is a one of those "comic staples."  Another way it's sometimes used: an action-hero (picture "Arnie") will say something like "I don't like nukes. They clash with my handbag." (Obviously, he doesn't have a handbag, and fashion considerations are humorously irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character is saying that kids would throw off the color scheme in his home -- in particular, they would not harmonize with the color of the curtains.

The character is speaking as if children were furniture, decorations, or other objects as possible additions to his home, and he is judging them (only) as such: To him, "having children" means adding them to his house.

He expresses the feeling that the appearance of his home and the things in it are highly important to him.

(It's a joke.)

Comment: The joke also plays on the stereotype that gay men have better fashion sense than straight men. In the context of the gay character the joke may also be hiding a regret that he has fathered no children.